# Interpolation of varying variable in fragment shaders under the hood

Tags: opengl, graphics

I have triangle with three vertrices v1, v2, v3 from ℝ<sup>3</sup> and texture coordinates t1, t2, t3. It is a linear surface with boundaries.

The interpolation as I see: 
Define a mapping "M" from that surface which is subset of ℝ<sup>3</sup> to (0,1)**2 with one constraint  M(v1)=t1; M(v2)=t2; M(v3)=t2;

**Is it exist more constraints to function "M"?**

The final aim is to "Rasterize" triangle in 2D "Window Space".

How to know what is texture coordinate for concrete rasterzied point of triangle?
I heard about couple methods how to do it.
**Is it exist others?**

1. Perform linear interpolation along the edges, and then make intepolation in scan line
2. Use barycentric coordinates of each point in ℝ<sup>3</sup> before it "rasterized" to ℝ<sup>2</sup>.  Then make an affine combination of "varying" variables t1,t2,t3

**Which schema is used in rasterization stage in modern hardware?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL uses barycentric coordinates for interpolating varying variables. I checked as far back as the OpenGL 2.1 spec, and it is described that way in a section titled "Basic Polygon Rasterization" (section 3.5.1, page 109), and looks basically unchanged in the latest 4.5 spec (section 14.6.1, page 451).

You can find the referenced spec documents in the [OpenGL Registry](https://www.opengl.org/registry/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Reto. I'd like to know answer for one more question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30302195/is-it-possible-generate-normal-map-from-heightmap-texture-from-math-point-of-vie But I can't find your email address, so I post it here in comments.