# Is it possible generate normal map from heightmap texture from math point of view?

Tags: opengl, graphics, computational-geometry

My view is that you can not generate normal map only from height map texture?
Am I right or not?

**Math Arguments:**

Assume that surface is given a continuous bijection from

[image]

S = [0,1]

T = [0,1]

Let's call SxT as image space.

It can be proved from differentional geometry that normal to that parametric surface is

[image]

**If assume that mapping from SxT image space to geometric euclidian space is very simple then we can retrive:**

[image]

Then you can calculate such partial derivatives with some difference scheme.
We came to that simple formula, only with **bold** suggestion and this suggestion is absolutely not true.

---

**Sample of the problem from graphics**.

Let assume we have triangle in geometric eclidian space with 3 vertices.
Terms are:

*normalmap* -- 
it is normal for point with (u,v,1-u-v) barycentric coordinates fetched from (u,v) from suitable 2d texture, and it is in local coord. system relative to triangle.

*heihtmap* -- 
it is geometric offset for point with (u,v,1-u-v) barycentric coordinates in normal direction relative to triangle localspace fetched from (u,v) from suitable 2d texture.

During building normalmap we absolutely ignore how heightmap is distributed near (u,v,1-u-v) eculidian point. And we retrive only some approximation of normal map.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281261/generating-a-normal-map-from-a-height-map

Comment: Thanks, I watched it before post a question. But It doesn't contain answer. It contains common implementation tricks. But I want to understand "fundamentals" of that operation.

Comment: IMHO, the only fundamental here is *cross product* of two vectors. If you know what it is, your task becomes easy.

Comment: Ok. I will make fixies in question, seems the question is ambiguous.

Comment: HolyBlackCat. Cross product it is fundamental block for a lot of stuff in math, physics, graphics...But I think that you not understand the question. The question is "Is it possible to generate normal map only from heightmap?" Many years ago when I implement it I calculate "geometric normals" based on "image space"....But now I realize that it is absolutely not correct....

Comment: @bruzzo Yes, it's possible, but you need to one other thing: height scale. (How high is absolute white and absolute black.) If you know that, you can 1. compute 3D coordinates of every pixel; 2. for each pixel, compute normals of 4 adjacent triangles; 3. for each pixel, compute average of these 4 normals and normalize it to get a normal of that point.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat. You introduce some height-scale, some color, pixels, 3d coordiantes of pixel(so it seems you introduce render geometry.)
I have only one input -- heightmap, no geometry, no camera, no pixels, no color. But I'd like to discuss method that you present.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat. Example from graphics why you need metioned X(s,t) and Y(s,t):
You apply heightmap to surface, imagine that your shrink, stretch in texture coordinates. Depend on it shrinks your texture coordinates your neighboor points (in geometry space) will have different height.
So it will have different form of surface, and of course it will have another normal at sampling point.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat. As I said I'm interesting in method that you present. So lets talks in computer graphics terms.

0. What is height-scale.
  Can I drop it. The range of values of H(s,t) is real nummbers. Imagine that F32 texture.

1. Compute 3D coordinates of every raterized pixel. 
  Is it geometry coordinates of rasterized geometry in camera space?

2. for each pixel, compute normals of 4 adjacent triangles
   What does it mean adjacence of triangles per pixel. I know that pixel can have 4 or 8 1-Ring neighboor pixels in image space.
And also where do I need a heightmap, you not mentioned it?

Comment: No markup in comments(((

Comment: By the way, for what you want to use these normal maps? For textures? Or for triangle/quad mesh?

Comment: I'd like after rasterization (which is sampling the environment in a discrete points of "window" grid) retrive correct normals per pixel

Comment: For the reasons of make discussion more shortly I think we can to view on some example of parametric surface -- "one triangle"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me my own initial question is invalid and it has a bug!!!

> I – original parametric surface with domain as cartesian product of [0,1] and range of it as euclidean space
>
> II - normal to original surface
>
> III - modified original surface with heightmap
>
> IV - normal map which we want to receive with even ignoring geometric modification of the surface by “III”

[image]

Final step IV includes a lot of stuff to differentiate: H(s,t) and original definition of the function...I don't perform futher analytic of that equations...But as for me you can't generate normalmap only from (heightmap)...

P.S. To perform futher analytics if you want to do it retrive *.docx file from that place https://yadi.sk/d/Qqx-jO1Ugo3uL As I know it impossible to convert formulas in ms word to latex, but in any case please use it asa draft.

Comment: It appears that your question is about displacement maps applied to curved surfaces, not just "heightmaps" in their traditional sense. In this case you, obviously, need to consider the base surface tangent space to adjust the heightmap normal to the world coordinates, which involves the differential (X,Y,Z)(s,t)/d(s,t).

Comment: There are two usable surface definition in computational geometry -- implicit zero-level set of scalar function of vector argument, and parametric surface definition, the last one can be "curved" or "linear"...."Draw me an array of triangles" - it is not a function definition. Sometimes you can define piecewise linear function in some manner and consider it....

Comment: I'm intersting in: Imagine you have one triangle with 3 vertices in space,  (u,v) texture coordinates per each vertex, some interpolation schema how to fetch texture values from that triangle surface....For example based on https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/version2.1/glspec21.pdf, "3.5.1 Basic Polygon Rasterization"....Question: Can I ignore ignore geometry in that case, and generate normalmap only from heightmap? (both of that maps has domain as [0,1]**2)

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, looks like my comment was too brief.

It's easier to write a full answer with code to describe the method.

I'm going to use a pseudocode mix of C++ and GLSL.

```
constexpr int width = 32, height = 32;
constexpr float height_scale = 16.0f; // Change if necessary.

float hmap[W][H] = {...};
float normalmap[W][H];

vec3 GetPoint(ivec2 a)
{
    a.x %= W;
    a.y %= H;
    return {a.x, a.y, hmap[a.x][a.y] * height_scale};
}

vec3 GetNormal(ivec2 a, bool loop_hmap)
{
    vec3 o = GetPoint(a),
         a = GetPoint({a.x + 1, a.y}),
         b = GetPoint({a.x, a.y + 1}),
         c = GetPoint({a.x - 1, a.y}),
         d = GetPoint({a.x, a.y - 1});
    vec3 n1 = normalize(cross(a-o, b-o));
    vec3 n2 = normalize(cross(b-o, c-o));
    vec3 n3 = normalize(cross(c-o, d-o));
    vec3 n4 = normalize(cross(d-o, a-o));

    if (loop_hmap)
        return normalize(n1+n2+n3+n4);
    else
    {
        vec3 sum = {0,0,0};
        bool b1 = (a.x+1 >= 0 && a.y >= 0 && a.x+1 < W && a.y < H);
        bool b2 = (a.x >= 0 && a.y+1 >= 0 && a.x < W && a.y+1 < H);
        bool b3 = (a.x-1 >= 0 && a.y >= 0 && a.x-1 < W && a.y < H);
        bool b4 = (a.x >= 0 && a.y-1 >= 0 && a.x < W && a.y-1 < H);
        if (b1 && b2) sum += n1;
        if (b2 && b3) sum += n2;
        if (b3 && b4) sum += n3;
        if (b4 && b1) sum += n4;
        return normalize(sum);
    }
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < H; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < W; j++)
            normalmap[j][i] = GetNormal(j, i, 0);
}
```

`loop_hmap` argument of `GetNormal()` changes how the function computes normals for edge pixels. `1` should be used for tiled textures, like sand and water. `0` should be used for nontiled textures, like items, mobs, trees.

Comment: Thanks for time spent write it.) Only one question normalize(dot(a-o, b-o)) what does mean normalization of scalar value? maybe it miss print and you mean normalize(cross(a-o,b-o))?

Comment: Let's discard edge case for localize problem in general. In method which I use some years ago I use a bit another schema to count normal  n(i,j) = ( (H(i+1,j) - H(i,j))*scale, (H(i,j+1) - H (i,j))*scale, 1). I mentioned it in question.

Comment: @bruzzo Shame on me, of course it's `cross`! Fixed. Your method is a lot faster, but it generates slightly different normal maps depending on a height map rotation. Also, it may be a bit less precise, but I'm not sure how much less.

Comment: Ok, My point is mine difference schema in previous comment, and I think that yours too are not correct ((((
Even it lead us to normal graphical result.

Comment: I'll update description because it is impossible to write it in comments.